# $addFields where condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to add extra field to lookup result but i need a condition here. Every user has a relationship status (local field) and it should be added to lookup result for each user, but It's adding every 'status' to every user.

```
db.getCollection('relationships').aggregate([
    {$match: {
        user_id: ObjectId("5d3dbe07ea97db13d5b73195")}
    },
    {
       $lookup:
         {
           from: 'users',
           localField: 'relationship.user_id',
           foreignField: '_id',
           as: 'userss'
         }
    },
        {
        $addFields: {
            "userss.status": "$relationship.status"
        }
    },

])
```

User Schema

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3dbe07ea97db13d5b73195"),
    "username" : "dipper",
    "email" : "test@test.com"
}
```

Realtionship Schema

```
{
    "user_id" : ObjectId("5d3dbe07ea97db13d5b73195"),
    "relationship" : [ 
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5d3dbe17ea97db13d5b73196"),
            "status" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5d3dbe28ea97db13d5b73197"),
            "status" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I need a result like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3dbe07ea97db13d5b73196"),
    "username" : "mabel",
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "status": 0

}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d3dbe07ea97db13d5b73197"),
    "username" : "wendy",
    "email" : "test@test.com",
"status": 1

}
```

Comment: How username is different as in your expected result? username should be `dipper` for two objects. No?

Comment: @HardikShah OP is trying to print the details for relationships

Comment: @mickl, Yes got it. I was referring upper `user_id` relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get single document per relationship:

```
db.relationships.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { user_id: ObjectId("5d3dbe07ea97db13d5b73195") }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$relationship"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "relationship.user_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "user"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$user"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id:  "$relationship.user_id",
            username: "$user.username",
            email: "$user.email",
            status: "$relationship.status"
        }
    }
])
```